# My Android spinner works without an ArrayAdapter...why?

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Will I come to the heaven or to the hell?
As I had to populate 5 spinners, I tried very compact code. I didn´t understand  why I should use a ArrayAdapter, so I simply dropped it out, in spite all tutorials use it. I was surpraised, as it worked. The code is showing only one spinner:

```
 Spinner s2_height = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.s2_height);
    s2_height.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {  //Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been selected.
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,  //Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been selected
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            myCalc();}
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
});
```

This is the location in my  .java, where I dropped out the ArrayAdapter section, normaly being in tutorials recomanded as:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.Height_array_id, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   s2_height.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And surprisingly, it worked, I placed a method myCalc which displays the ItemPosition on all 5 spinners correctly. Now I am afraid that I´ll get any drawback at another place, may be at changing colours, or text heights. Has somebody the same problem?

Comment: I think it works probably because you are assigning entries (android:entries) in the layout xml, as simple as that.

Answer (score 6):

> Will I come to the heaven or to the hell?

That would be a question for your priest, minister, rabbi, etc. It is not a relevant question for StackOverflow.

> I didn´t understand why I should use a ArrayAdapter, so I simply dropped it out

You do not have to use an `ArrayAdapter`, but you have to use some form of `SpinnerAdapter` to populate the `Spinner` via `setAdapter()`. Otherwise, the `Spinner` will be empty. If your `Spinner` is not empty, that means you called `setAdapter()` on it somewhere.

Comment: I experimented inserting the 4 lines of a standard ArrayAdapter code and removing it again. Both worked identically. I have definitely no kind of setAdapter() ahywhere. Can it be, that the newest SDK provides it in setOnItemSelectedListener automaticaly (hidden), if not explicitely coded?

Comment: @PedroJebeto: "I have definitely no kind of setAdapter() ahywhere." -- then your `Spinner` is empty, or you forgot to recompile/reinstall your application after making the code change.

Comment: The spinner in Android is like a castle with 7 locks. You can see how many similar faq´s are here posted, there is something wrong in the system. You cannot easily change spinner´s appearance, color, size, nothing. And it is the most basic stone of each app. Thanks for you help!